# How Can I Convert Microseconds to Human Readable Date & Time w/ Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

So I'm trying to convert the 'Event Time' (Time in microseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) column in a pandas data frame to human readable date & time.

Name of column: **df['Event Time']**

input: **df['Event Time'].iloc[0]**
output: **1519952249827533**

I need a script to transform the entire column.

I tried the following, but there needs to be something much more simple:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
cookie_microseconds_since_epoch = df['Event Time'].iloc[0]
cookie_datetime = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=cookie_microseconds_since_epoch)
str(cookie_datetime)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ok I added the code I worked on, can you please undo the thumbs down?

Comment: Your code is converting the timestamps to strings. Do you really want that, or do you want to keep them as timestamp objects (which you can do arithmetic and comparisons on—and which are smaller to store in memory and on disk, and faster to operate on) and only convert them to strings as needed for, say, outputting reports?

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and specify the `unit` as microseconds.  Mind that the microseconds unit is `us` (I didn't know that a few minutes ago (-:)

```
df['Event Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'], unit='us')
```

### MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event Time': [1519952249827533]})

df['Event Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'], unit='us').dt.floor('s')

df

           Event Time
0 2018-03-02 00:57:29
```

If you wanted a string result instead of `Timestamps` use `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'], unit='us').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

0    2018-03-02 00:57:29
Name: Event Time, dtype: object
```

See [strftime.org](http://www.strftime.org) for more info on using strftime.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error: OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 'ms'

Comment: Because they are nano seconds

Comment: I suspect they really are microseconds, like the OP says they are. 1519952249827533us after the epoch is 2018-03-02, which seems a lot more likely than 1970-01-18.

Comment: @abarnert in that case, one sec.

Comment: @UlisesSotomayor What you get is `Timestamp` objects, not strings. The decimal point is just part of its representation. When you need to print them out or otherwise convert them to strings, you do that at the time of printout/conversion.

Comment: @UlisesSotomayor In particular, `Timestamp('2018-03-02 00:57:29')` is the exact same value as `Timestamp('2018-03-02 00:57:29.000000')`

Comment: Still working on `ms` vs `ns` issue.  But you can use the `floor` method.  `pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'], unit='ns').dt.floor('s')`

Comment: Or `round`: `pd.to_datetime(df['Event Time'], unit='ns').dt.round('s')`

Comment: @piRSquared Microseconds are `us`, not `ms`; that's milliseconds. (And if you were trying to use `µs`, most of Pandas doesn't understand the micro sign, although there are a few random places that do.)

Comment: Well hot digity.  I didn't even pay attention to that.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I really appreciate the effort you took to explain this to me.

Comment: The only remaining question is whether the OP actually wants a string column (presumably in the default YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format for Pandas Timestamps, since that matches what his code does).

Comment: I'm getting 1970 as the year ...just realized that

Comment: @piRSquared I don't know what your background is, but engineers (as in mechanical, electrical, etc., not computer programmers) always get thrown by that. Outside of computers, the way you substitute `µ` in Latin is `mc`; in Fortran/C/etc., that would break all the code that expects prefixes to be a single byte, and besides, with a 1970s printer or monitor a `u` pretty much looks like a `µ`.

Comment: My educational path was going to lead me to math/physics.  I landed in finance instead.  Picked up programming more seriously last several years.